# How do I view server logs when using AWS Elastic Beanstalk / EC2? Do I need to use SSH?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed a Node.js application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. How do I view logs (like the output from console.logs) in real-time for the server? I'm able to SSH into the Linux instance, but am not sure what I need to do to view server logs from there if that's what's required. I know I can view the logs on the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard, but these aren't in real time and take a long time to load.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

try  `$tail -f /var/log/*` It gives all the logs. You can further filter it . `$cd /var/log` and check for the folders present. If you have used apache then use `$tail -f /var/log/apache2/*`

Comment: Hi Bijendra, thanks for the response... this isn't quite what I'm looking for though. I'd like to be able to view the console.log commnads in real time, similar to how I can view the log in real time if I run a node server on my local machine in the Mac terminal (ie when I run 'node server.js' or 'node app.js'). This will usually output things like GET and PUT requests, console logs, etc...

Comment: There are different log levels to be used when running application in production mode. I'm not aware of node.js but in rails it's debug mode which displays log commands in production logs.